# Xcode Undefined symbols for architecture i386:What does this error code mean, and how do I go about fixing it?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

How do I resolved this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

```
directory not found for option '-   L/Users/blank/Desktop/project/ipad_client/move/Modules/Unity/Libraries'
```

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
          "_AFNetworkingReachabilityDidChangeNotification", referenced from:
          -[moveChat startTrackingNetworkEvents] in moveChat.o

Comment: You may have forgotten to load one of the frameworks.  Perhaps the networking one, can't remember it's full name right now.  But I would check that first.

Comment: AFNetworking is a third party library. Make sure it's being linked with the target.